# How to Make Range Dynamic in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below, I have code that sends a personalized SMS message and includes the name. I got that part to work. Now, I just need to make it so that my range is dynamic and moves down the respective column until there is no one left to message. In it's current state, it will only message the first person. I tried looking up dynamic range tutorials, loops, etc. but they were either too complex for me to grasp or would require me to rewrite what I already have working.

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click()


   Dim contactNumberRange As Range
   Dim messageRange As Range
   Dim clientNameRange As Range
   Dim phoneCell As Range
   Dim messageCell As Range
   Dim nameCell As Range


   Set contactNumberRange = Range("D2") //Need to make this range dynamic
   Set messageRange = Range("E2") //This too
   Set clientNameRange = Range("A2") //This aswell


   For Each phoneCell In contactNumberRange
    For Each messageCell In messageRange
     For Each nameCell In clientNameRange
      SendMessage FROMPHONE, nameCell.Value, phoneCell.Value, messageCell.Value
     Next
    Next
   Next





 Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to ammend your ranges with a last row variable.

Also, qualify those ranges with a worksheet!

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim LR As Long
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set contactNumberRange = ws.Range("D2:D" & LR)
Set messageRange = ws.Range("E2:E" & LR)
Set clientNameRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & LR)

For Each phoneCell In contactNumberRange
    For Each messageCell In messageRange
        For Each nameCell In clientNameRange
            SendMessage FROMPHONE, nameCell.Value, phoneCell.Value, messageCell.Value
        Next nameCell
    Next messageCell
Next phoneCell
```

Comment: To me the next question will be, "why is this sending so many text messages?"  I would think a single loop would do what the OP really wants.  but that is not the scope of this question, just a thought.

Comment: I had the same thought of concatenating the strings and just send 1 message to each person -

Comment: Well, this didn't work. When I tested using range set to one cell per range, it sent a concatenated message. Using this code, it spammed and message was broken up. I guess I have to rewrite code so I can use this.